# CDH 5.5 Pig stuck at 0%

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I have installed CDH 5.3 cluster on Ubuntu, I respected all the configurations recommended by Cloudera, it has hadoop + HBase.

The problem arise when i try to load the data and dump it using PIG the job is still stagnate, and I always reload 0%

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64

Parcel CDH 5.3 (or 5.5.1)

```
Job : a = load '/user/nadir/data.txt' ; dump a ;
```

*logs:*

```
2016-02-12 04: 06: 33.869 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1455246282704_0001
2016-02-12 04: 06: 33.869 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing has aliases
2016-02-12 04: 06: 33.869 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: a [1,4] C: R:
2016-02-12 04: 06: 34.121 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% Complete
```

Comment: see if you have nodemanagers up and running also track the job on resource anger UI